# Input control value is not updated properly from ngModelChange

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm having trouble updating an input while the user types.

I need to get a code from the user that looks like this: 354e-fab4 (2 alphanumeric groups of 4 chars separated by '-'). The user is not supposed to type the '-', it is inserted automatically.
When the user types something that doesn't match the regexp used for validation, I want to revert back to the previous valid value.

The problem is that the value in the input is not updated properly when the validation fails. On the other hand, if I set a hard-coded string, the value is reflected in the input.

I isolated the problem in a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qsbtiz

You may reproduce the issue by typing more than 8 characters: the regexp test fails, the code is set to the previous value, but the value is not reflected in the HTML input.

This is the method called for when the value of the input changes:

```
onCodeChange(newValue: string) {
    const previousValue = this.code;
    this.code = newValue;
    const regex = new RegExp(/^([a-z0-9]{0,4})?(-)?([a-z0-9]{0,4})?(-)?$/);

    // If the code doesn't match the regex, revert to the old value and return.
    if (!regex.test(newValue)) {

        // This changes this.code, but it's not reflected in the input's value.
        this.code = previousValue;

        // This changes this.code and it is reflected in the input's value.
        //this.code = '1234';
    } else {
        const groups = regex.exec(newValue);
        if (!groups[2] && groups[3]) {
            this.code = `${groups[1]}-${groups[3]}`;
        }
    } 
}
```

Please note that I'm interested in what's wrong with this code, not in an alternative solution like using a custom masked input component.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you spliting `[(ngModel)]`. I would recommend to set it by passing the element it self to the `onCodeChange()` function:
[Stackbliz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rpmd4r?file=src/app/input/input.component.ts)

In template :

```
<input #input type="text" placeholder="" (ngModelChange)="onCodeChange($event,input)" [ngModel]="code"/>
```

In your TS file:

```
  code = '';
  previousValue = ''

  onCodeChange(newValue: string, input) {
    this.code = newValue;
    const regex = new RegExp(/^([a-z0-9]{0,4})?(-)?([a-z0-9]{0,4})?(-)?$/);

    if (!regex.test(newValue)) {
      console.log("No match. Reverting the code to the previous value (this is not working as expected).");
      input.value = this.previousValue;
    } else {
      const groups = regex.exec(newValue);
      if (!groups[2] && groups[3]) {
        this.code = `${groups[1]}-${groups[3]}`;
      }
      //Save previousValue here instead
      this.previousValue = this.code
    } 
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, Ethan. This seems to be the answer. However, I'm curious why my code was broken? Wasn't the property binding supposed to handle the value setting?

Comment: It because the when you splitting the [(ngModel)], you have to do the binding yourself, the (ngModelChange) event emitter does not set the value for you, it only emit the event, as well as [ngModel] only bind the value to the TS, not backward.

Comment: I think it's the other way around (or maybe I misunderstood your comment...): `[ngModel]="code"` means that when `code` changes, the input value changes. The equivalent of `[(ngModel)]="code"` is `<input [ngModel]="code" (ngModelChange)="code = $event" />`. That's why I don't get why in my version of `onCodeChange()` some assignments to `this.code` are reflected in the input while others are not.

Comment: For me, i dont really have a absolute answer for you but If you look at the actually code of the ngModel directive below, from line 221, then follow it to the file `shared.ts` to line 153, i believe the function `isPropertyUpdated()`  always return `false` except for the first time change, and i think that caused the problem. 
 https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restore the previous value then you should declare `previousValue` and assign the value like this.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vdqbxz

And I changed the `onModelchange` event to `keyup` because the groups were not generating properly for some reason(IMO thats not related to this post).

Comment: Thanks for the code. Indeed, it works, but what can be done about the nasty typing effect (the delay between the appearance and removal of a not-accepted character)?

Also, what would be the explanation for the initial code not working properly?